# Iphone app crashes before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, uistoryboard

My iPhone application was working properly and suddenly it crashes whenever i run it on the device or simulator and it doesn't report me with any useful info at the log it just logs the following useless info.:

```
2014-02-05 17:09:34.069 TeacherAssistant[711:60b] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2ed4ce9b <redacted> + 154
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x390a96c7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2   UIKit                               0x3197beed <redacted> + 0
3   UIKit                               0x3174a10d <redacted> + 44
4   UIKit                               0x3153ba53 <redacted> + 482
5   UIKit                               0x314d6a07 <redacted> + 3142
6   UIKit                               0x314d5cfd <redacted> + 72
7   UIKit                               0x3153b321 <redacted> + 664
8   GraphicsServices                    0x339bb76d <redacted> + 608
9   GraphicsServices                    0x339bb357 <redacted> + 34
10  CoreFoundation                      0x2ed17777 <redacted> + 34
11  CoreFoundation                      0x2ed17713 <redacted> + 346
12  CoreFoundation                      0x2ed15edf <redacted> + 1406
13  CoreFoundation                      0x2ec80471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
14  CoreFoundation                      0x2ec80253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
15  UIKit                               0x3153a5c3 <redacted> + 762
16  UIKit                               0x31535845 UIApplicationMain + 1136
17  TeacherAssistant                    0x0006c545 main + 220
18  libdyld.dylib                       0x395a2ab7 <redacted> + 2
)
```

please consider in your answer the following:

- I 'm putting a break point for all exceptions
- I tried to put an empty view controller and made it `the initial view controller` in order to know if the problem is in the storyboard but it crashes also
- I removed the app from the iPhone device and made clean/build but with no mean
- I removed all app derived data and made clean/build but also with no mean
- the provisioning profile is ok

and the following is the log when i tried it on the simulator:

```
2014-02-05 17:19:17.950 TeacherAssistant[17535:70b] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x017be5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015418b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   UIKit                               0x007e3572 -[UIStoryboard name] + 0
3   UIKit                               0x002af432 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 53
4   UIKit                               0x002af6e9 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
5   UIKit                               0x002ae28f -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 543
6   UIKit                               0x002c287c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
7   UIKit                               0x002c2de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
8   UIKit                               0x002b0025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
9   GraphicsServices                    0x020f52f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
10  GraphicsServices                    0x020f4e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
11  CoreFoundation                      0x01739d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
12  CoreFoundation                      0x01739a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
13  CoreFoundation                      0x0176477c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
14  CoreFoundation                      0x01763ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
15  CoreFoundation                      0x017638db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
16  UIKit                               0x002adadd -[UIApplication _run] + 840
17  UIKit                               0x002afd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
18  TeacherAssistant                    0x0000a67d main + 157
19  libdyld.dylib                       0x02b5e70d start + 1
)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: `[UIStoryboard name]` this is not available in UIKit and you are sending a `name` message to your storyboard at some point of your code or designer. Please verify.

Comment: what do you mean i'm not understanding !

Comment: not true. `[UIStoryboard name]` is a valid method. It's just not public, but it is available. This is not the problem. The problem is most likely inside the storyboard. There should be a message attached to this exception. E.g. "This class is not key-value compliant to key..."

Comment: @Matthias Bauch I tried to put an empty view controller and made it the initial view controller in order to know if the problem is in the storyboard but it crashes also

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your target has the correct name entered for your storyboard file. I was able to reproduce your error by going to the Info.plist file for my target, and renaming the storyboard so it didn't match the actual storyboard filename. My guess is either you accidentally renamed that in your target or you changed the filename of your storyboard at some point.

Comment: No, the problem was that the storyboard wasn't added in the bundle path section

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if your application uses embedded binaries, but you haven't added them in Target > General > Embedded Binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar strange problem. The app would crash before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, as you said.  I tried some of the suggestions related to making sure the storyboard file is correct in the plist, and is properly selected for the target.

My problem was that I was referencing a font in my plist that did not exist. I had changed fonts, and forgot to change it in my plist.