# Signal SIGABRT before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, sigabrt

I've been working on a refactor for an app lately. After converting classes into structs I ran the app and it crashed. I removed everything from the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, set up breakpoints to find the source and I ran into Signal SIGABRT even before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`was called. What can it be and how do I cope with it?

*All my Outlets are fine, the app crashes before any of the View Controllers being initialized.*

UPD: Console says nothing except

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

And I didn't touch anything related to Storyboard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961514/app-crashing-immediately-on-start-up-on-device-only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581260/iphone-app-crashes-before-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint

Comment: @user1046037 thank you, I totally forgot about it!